# No windscreen washer fluid coming through (VW Passat 1997)

Tags: windshield-washer, passat

When I pull back the stalk to squirt washer fluid onto the windscreen, 1997 Passat, the wipers move but no fluid comes out. There's not even the sound of anything trying to come out. Does this mean that the pump has gone?

As a side note I've replaced the comfort control module to try to fix it to no avail and I can't see any kinks in the hose leading to the nozzles. The washer fluid tank is also full, can being overfull be a problem?

Answer (score 5):

If you dont hear any buzzing sound from the pump then.

1. Check for a blown fuse.
2. If the fuse is intact then remove the pump and take it to a mechanic to fix or replace.Also if possible check the wiring.

Overfilling does not cause any problem as long as the pump is working.

[Fuse Location for VW Passat](http://danzuc.blogspot.in/2010/11/passat-b5-fusebox-location.html)

*Note:Number 24 is the fuse for windscreen washer motor.*

Comment: Ah fuse, didn't think of that! Cheers

Comment: Glad could help :-)